# I cannot install ROS in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
and got
Media Change: Please insert the disc labelled
'Ubuntu 12.10 *Quantal Quetzal* - Release amd64 (20121017.5)'
in the drive ‘/media/cdrom/’ and press enter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60837/i-cannot-install-ros-in-ubuntu-12.10/) by [saranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/4524/saranya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you still have the CD ROM option ticked in your Software Sources:

[image: image description]

If ticked, Ubuntu will install packages from the installation media rather than downloading from the internet.

After un-ticking it, reboot the system and follow the steps given [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu), that should do.

**Update:**

Open the sources.list file in /etc/apt folder. Check if the first line that points to CD-ROM is un-commented. If un-commented, comment it and try the `apt-get` command.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/4524/saranya/) on 2013-04-16**:
Thank you for your answer but I did not tick install from CD-Rom and I try to run is still happen again.

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-04-16**:
I have updated my answer. Please check.

**Comment by [saranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/4524/saranya/) on 2013-04-17**:
Thank you.It works.